# Is there a smart way of generating dplyr statements from a list of arguments"

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Consider the following function which has 6 arguments that can be passed and have 2^6=64 possible outcomes. This quickly grows to unmanageable numbers as the list of parameters grows.

```
expl<-function(patt=NULL,yearwise=T,monthwise=F,for_year=NULL,bankwise=T,categ=NULL,df=allst)
```

The code currently looks something like this (I have pasted only the first few if-then statements to give an idea).

```
if(!is.null(for_year) && is.null(patt)){
    if(bankwise && monthwise)
        allst %>% mutate(yr=year(date),mth=month(date,abbr = T)) %>% group_by(yr,mth,bank) %>% summarise(counttx=n(),sumcredit=sum(credit,na.rm = T), sumdebit=sum(debit,na.rm = T)) %>% filter(yr==for_year) else
            if(bankwise && !monthwise)
                allst %>% mutate(yr=year(date)) %>% group_by(yr,bank) %>% summarise(counttx=n(),sumcredit=sum(credit,na.rm = T), sumdebit=sum(debit,na.rm = T)) %>% filter(yr==for_year) else
                    if(monthwise && !bankwise)
                        allst %>% mutate(yr=year(date),mth=month(date,abbr = T)) %>% group_by(yr,mth) %>% summarise(counttx=n(),sumcredit=sum(credit,na.rm = T), sumdebit=sum(debit,na.rm = T)) %>% filter(yr==for_year) else
                            if(!monthwise && !bankwise) message("You have to select at least one of the two as TRUE: monthwise or bankwise")
} else  .....
```

I am sure there is a better way like using a switch but even switch gets unwieldy. Do we have any package or a better way to handle this growing list of arguments that just need incremental changes in a dplyr pipe?